# Why does NDepend count Static fields as LOC for a method

Tags: ndepend, lines-of-code

I have a type to define and assign some static readonly fields.
I got a violation for Methods too big (LOC)

I would like to know if I have an attribute for method, and used it in the rule (see below). Where is in my source code I need to use this attribute to discard "this and which" method?

Example code:

[image]

Sample rule:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Why does NDepend count Static fields as LOC for a method*

It is because when you do a static field inline initialization, it adds a line of code to the class constructor. Actually, as soon as you have one static field inline initialization in a class, the C# compiler creates a static constructor for your class. So if you have N static field inline initialization, you have a method (the class constructor) that has N Lines of Code.

The large method that NDepend reports here is named `BassAttributeNames..cctor()`. Certainly the easiest way to adapt your code rule to avoid such match is to add the clause:

`&& !m.IsClassContructor`